# How to show directions in SwiftUI Map()

Tags: swiftui, apple-maps

I am using Map in SwiftUI 3 and Xcode 13+

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI
import MapKit

Map(coordinateRegion: $mapViewModel.region,
                    interactionModes: [.all],
                    showsUserLocation: true,
                    userTrackingMode: .constant(.none),
                    annotationItems: annotations) { place in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: place.placemark.location!.coordinate) {
                        MapPinView()
                    }
                }
                    .tint(.blue)
                    .environmentObject(mapViewModel)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onAppear {
                        mapViewModel.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled()
                        
                    }
```

So, here I am using Map(...)

Is there any example for showing a route between 2 points?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Beginning in IOS 17 you can use `MapPolyline` and pass a list of `CLLocation2DCoordinates` (along with other instantiation approaches).

If you don't want to require IOS 17 you will need to follow to approach in Mircea's answer.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mappolyline
Apple provides an example at minute 22 in: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/

Answer (score 1):

From this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6pmm62axCg

You have the sources here: https://github.com/apatronl/YouTube/blob/main/Directions/Directions/ContentView.swift

And here is the relevant code snippet:

```swift
let request = MKDirections.Request()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: p1)
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: p2)
    request.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate { response, error in
      guard let route = response?.routes.first else { return }
      mapView.addAnnotations([p1, p2])
      mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
      mapView.setVisibleMapRect(
        route.polyline.boundingMapRect,
        edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20),
        animated: true)
      self.directions = route.steps.map { $0.instructions }.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    }
```

Comment: This is not using Map() of the SwiftUI .. i am using this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map

Comment: Map that you are using is part of MapKit. You cannot use that default view to render what you need, you need to create a custom view. This is what they do in that github file.

You can also look at this tutorial who does something similar https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/advanced-mkmapview-with-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

## For MapKit for SwiftUI (iOS17)

As mentioned in a reply already Apple provided the code in the [Meet MapKit for SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043) WWDC23 session.
Note that you still use MKRoute, the SwiftUI addition is the MapPolyline view. This code is just an example and it can be refined depending of your implementation. I recommend to watch the session though.

The code is this:

```swift
// example
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static var start = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.7071, longitude: 0.2064)
    static var end = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.734, longitude: 0.222)
}
...
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var route: MKRoute?
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?

    var body: some View {
        Map(selection: $selectedResult) {

             // assuming you have a marker here
              Marker("End", coordinate: .end)

              if let route {
                MapPolyline(route)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
              }
        }
    }
    func getDirections() {
        route = nil
        guard let selectedResult else { return }
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: .start))
        request.destination = selectedResult
        
        Task {
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            let response = try? await directions.calculate()
            route = response?.routes.first
            print(route?.expectedTravelTime.formattedToString ?? "No route")
        }
    }
}
```